# How do you setup a RubyMine rails project to work with a remote ruby install?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, project, virtualbox, rubymine

My dev machine is running Windows, IntelliJ Idea 13 (EAP), and VirtualBox. I run a virtual linux server with ruby (setup to match the production server I'll deploy to). I have configured IntelliJ to use the ruby SDK on the (virtually) remote server, but I am having problems creating new rails projects because it is trying to pass windows local paths to the remote ruby install.

On my windows, I try to create the project in D:\Projects\MyRubyProject

On the VM, that dir maps to /projects/MyRubyProject

In the new project dialog, I would like to set the content root to /projects/MyRubyProject, but if I do it says it doesnt exists and ask to create it, when it creates it, it is created in the IntelliJ install dir. I tried giving it the same type of ssh:// path that the remote SDK accepts, but it just silentl fails.

Any suggestions or is this something that is just not supported?

Answer (score 0):

i tried also.

just use "Configuring Remote Interpreters via Virtual Boxes" https://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/webhelp/configuring-remote-interpreters-via-virtual-boxes.html

Rubymine don't offer the possibility to create new rails project remotely.